# Using chained selects with AJAX , PHP & MVC

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

So I want to create a form with chained links where choosing a country gives you a state and a state gives a city. I've setup my db and tables and I've written my ajax code. The list of countries comes up well, but after selecting a country, the ajax doesn't get the selected `country_id` to populate the state field, vice versa.
Im using an mvc framework similar to codeigniter, plz i need help.

**This is my ajax call and html which is on the view:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo URL?>patient_appointment/getstate',
                data:'country_id='+countryID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                    $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });

    $('#state').on('change',function(){
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        if(stateID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo URL?>patient_appointment/getcity',
                data:'state_id='+stateID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#city').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
  </script>
 <select name="country" id="country">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
            <?php if ($total_countries > 0) { foreach ($country as $key => $value) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $value['country_id'] ?>"><?php echo $value['country_name'] ?></option>
                            <?php }} else { echo "<option value=''>No data in database</option>"; } ?>
                        </select>

    <select name="state" id="state">

        <option value="">Select country first</option>
    </select>

    <select name="city" id="city">
        <option value="">Select state first</option>
    </select>
                        <div name="state" id="state"></div>
```

This is my **Controller**:

```
function index() 
    {   
        $this->view->data['country']=$this->model->getcountries();
        $this->view->data['total_countries']=$this->model->gettotalcountries();
        if (isset($_POST['country_id'])) {
            $country_id = $_POST['country_id'];

        $this->view->data['info1']=$this->model->getdata1($country_id);
        $this->view->data['total_info1']=$this->model->gettotaldata1($country_id);
    }
        $this->view->render('patient_appointment/index', $noinclude=false, 2);
    }

    function getstate()
    {

        if(isset($_POST["country_id"]) && !empty($_POST["country_id"])){
            $country_id=$_POST['$country_id'];
            $this->view->data['total_states']=$this->model->gettotalstates($country_id);
            $this->view->data['state']=$this->model->getstates($country_id); 

        }
    }
```

This is my **Model**:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getcountries()
    {
        $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY country_name ASC");
            $rowss=$sth->rows;
            return $rowss;
    }
    public function gettotalcountries()
    {
        $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY country_name ASC");
            $rowss=$sth->num_rows;
            return $rowss;
    }
    public function getstates($country_id)
    {
        $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id = '$country_id' AND status = 1 ORDER BY state_name ASC");
            $rowss=$sth->rows;
            return $rowss;
    }
    public function gettotalstates($country_id)
    {
        $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id = '$country_id' AND status = 1 ORDER BY state_name ASC");
            $rowss=$sth->num_rows;
            return $rowss;
    }
```

please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have two elements with same `id` i.e. `id="state"` (`select` element and a `div`). `id` should be unique in a document. This might be the problem.

Comment: Try `data: {country_id: countryID},`

Comment: @abhishekkannojia i removed the div element, still no response

Comment: @RiggsFolly not working either

Comment: How are you troubleshooting this? Are there any error messages? What you are doing now is basically saying 'here is my code that doesn't work, please fix it".

Answer (score 2):

Sould this line

```
$country_id=$_POST['$country_id'];
```

be

```
$country_id=$_POST['country_id'];
```

Or actually [the CI method](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data) is

```
$country_id = $this->input->post('country_id');
```

Comment: That''s an awful mistake, thanks. I've corrected it but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Are you returning anything from the getstate() function like a view?